# Detect whether a schedule is enabled for Android Night/Dark mode

Tags: android, accessibility, android-darkmode

I'd like to know whether a schedule is enabled to automatically switch day/night themes (ie based on sunset time). Is this possible? I'm building a library, so user interaction is not an option.

Detecting whether night or dark theme is currently active is easy enough, that is not the topic of this question.

Use-case: accessibility-related analytics library.